# Unwanted empty page from combining textblock* and spacing environments

Tags: spacing, environments, setspace, textpos

How can I get rid of the extra blank page that is apparently caused in this example by combining `spacing` and `textblock*` environments?

There's one restriction: the entire content of the `spacing` environment is in a separate `input` file. So moving the `textblock*` environment out of the `spacing`-environment is not easily possible.

`\begin{spacing}` with line height `{1}` is obviously redundant. I use different line heights in the real document.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[absolute,showboxes]{textpos}
\geometry{paperwidth=6cm, paperheight=2.61cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1}
\begin{textblock*}{2.5cm}(3cm,1cm)
Boxline1

Boxline2
\end{textblock*}
Line1

Line2

Line3

Line4
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm: nothing springs to mind as a cause for this. I'll take it as a [bugreport](https://bitbucket.org/nxg/textpos/issues/9/), but can't make any promises about a fix timescale.  Thanks for the excellent MWE.

Comment: Thanks @NormanGray. Appreciate your work on the very useful `textpos` package.